# Creating and using an Elixir helpers module in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a group of acceptance tests I've created in my faux blog phoenix app.  There's some duplicated logic between them I'd like to move to a helpers module to keep things DRY.

Here is the directory structure:

```
test/acceptance/post
├── create_test.exs
├── delete_test.exs
├── helpers.exs
├── index_test.exs
└── update_test.exs
```

The `helpers.exs` file is where I'd like to stick the duplicated acceptance test logic.  It looks something like:

```rb
defmodule Blog.Acceptance.Post.Helpers do
  def navigate_to_posts_index_page do
    # some code
  end
end
```

Then in one of my test files, say `index_test.exs`, I'd like to import the helpers module to use it's methods:

```rb
defmodule Blog.Acceptance.Post.IndexTest do 
  import Blog.Acceptance.Post.Helpers
end
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> ** (CompileError) test/acceptance/post/index_test.exs:7: module Blog.Acceptance.Post.Helpers is not loaded and could not be found

How do I get access to or load the helper module in my test files?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To make the `test_helpers.exs` Helpers module available, you'd need to use `Code.require_file` to load it; however, in this case phoenix configured your project to compile `.ex` files in `test/support` into the project exactly for cases like this. So if you place your module in `test/support/test_helpers.ex`, it will be compiled with your project and available to all test files without having to `Code.require_file` it.

Comment: Thanks, Chris!  Works like a charm. ;)  I like the Code.require_file approach in this case because it allows me to keep the helper file in the same directory.  But, once I start identifying logic that's shared across resources, the test/support/test_helpers.ex approach will be a great solution.